# sustainsys | multiple idp | challenge

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I am developping a application in .net c# (not netcore). This application is using sustainsys library to create multiple saml2 idps. I am adding the IdentityProvider's in startup.auth.cs->configureauth.
My problem is that when i want to do the challenge to use one specific idp i need to have this idp added in the context.environment (something like *context.Environment.Add("saml2.idp", new EntityId("idpid"));*)
I have seen that in netcore we have the option to do it, setting schema, in the same place where we create the IdentityProvider's (in the startup.cs).
How can I do it in .net?
Thanks in advance for your help!

I have tried but I don't find the way to do it in .net.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using Owin? Or the HttpModule?